# When did the sound change from t in PIE to th in Proto-Germanic?

Tags: sound-change

From Proto-Indo-European, the t sound sometimes changed to th in Proto-Germanic, which in turn gave English the same th sound. However, I'm not sure when this change happened. I watched a video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ky7SjFRsFs and it showed a th sound. So, when did the sound change happen? (It seems to have happened before ~750 BCE because that is when Pre-Proto-Germanic was spoken.)

Extra: Could the sound change happen in the opposite direction? What I mean by this is the th sound changing to t again in part because of the sound and spelling. (It has already happened in some Germanic languages, and an example outside of Germanic is the th in greek changing to t in spanish)

Comment: around the time that p shifted to f, why do you ask? also, for all I know 750 BC was only 2000 years ago, exactly, and Germanic was invented by Wulfila to accommodate the Gothen king's lisp, because nobody dared confront him about and people grew weary of playing the embassadors new cloth around him. If I recall correctly. In other words: What's your evidence for a 750 BC unified PGmc as reconstructed?

Comment: If you state that you know it *has* happened in the opposite direction (which it definitely has), why do you ask whether it *can*? It did, so it can...

Comment: @LjL the way I understand that part of the question, it's not clear whether /*t/ in all descendents stems from a reversal, or was remaining unchanged throughout, or--since we are not entirely sure about the phonetic value of PIE \*t, whether its IPA("th") that is the constant, though typologically unlikely.

Comment: Related part of the Wikipedia talk page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AGrimm's_law#Dating_Grimm's_Law

Answer (score 5):

The sound law that explains how /t/ turned into /θ/ is called Grimm's law; I would recommend reading up on it in literature on on Wikipedia. The subsequent law that explains how /ð/ appeared is called Verner's law, which I would recommend looking up after Grimm's law since it operates on the results of that.

Faroese is the modern Germanic language that I would say most cleanly has turned /θ/ into /t/ again. Late Old Swedish, 15th-16th century specifically, also turned word-initial /θ/ into /t/, but that happened after a previous sound change that also changed /θ/ into /ð/ in short words (almost identially to how "them", "thou" and "then" start with /ð/ in English), and since /ð/ turned into /d/, and was written as such, the results are less obvious in Swedish. The same would probably hold for Danish, but I know less about medieval Danish and how it lost its dental fricatives.

Comment: calling somebody to "reading up on" is not an answer, and rather impolite.

Comment: Faroese also has a double reflex of word-initial /θ/: it is /h/ in function words, /t/ elsewhere

Comment: @vectory: The OP has clearly not identified Grimm's Law or done any further research (they "watched a video"). Obviously they need to do some, because there's tons of stuff on the web about it. Under those circumstances, I think being told to read up on something is quite appropriate and certainly not rude.

Answer (score 1):

The change t > fricative th must be dealt with the whole picture of PIE voiceless stops becoming fricatives in Proto-Germanic. That is to say: p t k > f th h.
Indeed, this is the first mutation of Germanic.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimm%27s_law
As far as dating is concerned, it's hard to be precise. We can see that:
1. Germanic languages had already acquired their specific look, when they began to be written,
2. When Germanic languages got in contact with Latin, new words like *kat "cat" and *kasi "cheese" did not undergo the change. So the change is older than the Roman Empire.
3. There are also Celtic-Germanic contact words like *bukk- = buck, I suppose some people have studied them.
All this suggests the change must be significantly older than the Common Era, possibly even going into the second millennium BCE.
Besides, the first mutation of Germanic is in fact two changes: consonants changed and stress changed. These changes are major rearrangements of the language. This must have taken a quite long period of time.

Comment: As for cheese, consider *Hütten-Käse*, (literally cottage cheese, but fits \*k > \*h; cp *ferment* vs Fr *fermer* "to close, shut")

Comment: Whereas \*k can as well come from \*gw- (compare "to come"), also in Armenien btw. That's \*b in Hellenic, hence *cow* ~ *bous*, *bovine*. This also explains *cum*, perhaps, cp Ger *Kuppenkäse* "dick cheese", haha. I was actually hoping to find *kwas*, the fermented milk yoghurt drink, but have no idea where that came from and I won't search now. The romance word for cheese is chiefly *fromag-*, not *casa* "house", so why would we not borrow that? Questions over questions.

Comment: *kasi "cheese" is obviously from Latin case(um), not casa.

Comment: I don't know what's obvious about it. Loans from Latin into Germanic proper are rarely admitted and without known historic pathway.

Comment: The wordplay with *casa* was no mistake. Incidently, when I looked up *leather* for its development of *Th*, I found: Armenian translation կաշի (kaši), supposedly with a relation to Semitic. That can't possibly have anything to do with cheese. Let's see Latin *aluta* "leather", assigned a root akin to *aluminum*; AGr *bursa*; modern Greek *derma* (again cp *ferm-*, if by stretch of the imagination \*d- ~ \*dh- can be explained). *leather* and *cheese* were trade items and it stands to reason that "cover, skin" fits what I implied before.

Comment: now what about *cat*? Ger *Katze* shows . in the dental, or where's the /tz/ from?

Comment: What about *cat*? It only appears in Late Latin and Pfeiffer still thought it earlier in Insular Celtic and Germanic. Wiktionary had a lengthy discussion about the supposedly Egyptian origin "bobcat". Incidently, like *Hütten-Käse*, there is also a compounded *Haus-Katze*, in contradistinction to *wild-* (likewise for *Schwein*, though); cp *Haustier* "pet animal" vs *pussy*, *pussy-cat* (likewise uncertain, and for obvious reasons). OHG *kazza* is notable. French *chat* does chow palatization. *Catherine* shows *th* in disagreement with AGr, supposedly from Romans equating *katharos* "pure".

Comment: Tz in Katze is due to the second German mutation, which turned t into tz, p into pf, and in Switzerland also k and kch.

Comment: A good example for a shift that was not total, potentially only orthographic until later. There's a good argument to be made analog to *pus* above that Ger *Musch*, *Muschi*, *Miez, Miezekatze* "pussy, pussycat" reflects \*miskaz, from \*mew or \*mey "small, fine thing" (viz *mini*), with sk-present. Now I assume \*-k-az was rebracketed. *z* and *tz* are homographs, by the way, so I had first looked up *Mietze* and thus helpless resorted to *Miete* "rent, loan; heap [of e.g. hay]" and took a double take because the latter sense derived from *meta*, explained as *cone, pyramid*: Pyramietzekatz!